# Installed Wine programs don't show up in deepin menu

Tags: wine, appmenu

I am running Ubuntu with the Deepin desktop. Everything is working as expected except that my wine apps don't show up in the application menu. I installed Microsoft Office because I need that specific program for what I'm doing. The `/home/caden/.local/share/applications/wine` folder is there with the Office apps and I can execute the apps through the .desktop files. For some reason, the apps don't show in the application menu. How can I get these icons to show up in the Deepin menu?

It's also worth mentioning that when I had Lubuntu installed the Wine folder and apps showed up just fine.